# Database Selection Via ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, ado.net

I have a `combobox` that I would like to use to select the database from a selection available to the user. I have found plenty of information on populating the fields with table values but nothing on making a selection on which `.dbo` they can use. I'm guessing the same principle can be used as below...
but I would presume that (`database =`) needs to be taken out and replaced some how. 
any advice would be appreciated

```
var connectionString = "server = (local); database = database; integrated security = true;"
string Sql = "select database...";
SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
_con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    combobox1.Items.Add(reader[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this query;

```
string Sql = "SELECT * FROM sys.databases";
```

Comment: So its more down to what SQL query i send then? 
sorry the example didn't work, but that's more likely my end I Guess.

Comment: @JamesBurnieMcburnie What is your database? Isn't it SQL Server?

Comment: It is, sorry turns out its actually further up in my code and this isn't being executed at the right point causing it not to populate before it is shown to the User.
Working now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can remove database option from connection string and execute sql query against `master.dbo.sysdatabases`.

Complete example:

```
var connectionString = "server=(local);integrated security=true;"
string sql = "SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases";
SqlConnection conn= new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            combobox1.Items.Add(reader["name"]);

        }
```